# Having trouble obtaining a query parameter on a views page

Tags: views, 8

I have successfully created a custom contextual link to create a "picture" node linked to the current "artefact" node:

```
    function tanw_contextual_links_view_alter(&$element, $items) {
      if (isset($element['#contextual_links']['node'])
             && in_array($element['#contextual_links']['node']['metadata']['ds_bundle'], ['artefacts','events'])) {
        $entity = entity_load('node', $element['#contextual_links']['node']['route_parameters']['node']);
          {do my thing with the entity}
```

But now I am completely stuck trying to add the very same link to a views page that shows all pictures linked to a given "artefact". The nid is in the url:

```
http://MY_DOMAIN/manage_photos?node=32006
```

The following code seems to pick up the correct context for adding the link:

```
  else if (isset($element['#contextual_links']['entity.view.edit_form'])
         && $element['#contextual_links']['entity.view.edit_form']['metadata']['name']
== 'photo_slideshow' )
```

But for the life of me I cannot find a way of prying the node query parameter value either out of the URL or out of elsewhere.

The $element array for the views context doesn't contain the query parameters anywhere. \Drupal::request()->query returns NULL for some inexplicable reason. While exploring the request object, the only part where I even see the query parameters is buried somewhere under ->server in HTTP_REFERRER of all places. Of course I can try to extract what I need from there but it looks like a horrible last resort kind of hack I am not yet ready to resort to.
I am feeling that I am missing something obvious and/or looking in a wrong place. Will appreciate any pointers to the right place.

PS I just realized that the "current path" for the hook context is /contextual/render as it seems to be a separate ajax request from the main page request and the main request query parameters are no longer relevant here. So the question is: how do I obtain the main page request?

Comment: UPDATE: Having found no elegant way to obtain the query parameter, I extracted it from HTTP_REFERER and immediately bumped into another wall: apparently contextual links for views are cached regardless of the query parameters, so an attempt to link a picture to any further artefact links it instead to the artefact on which the contextual links were first rendered. Any way to adjust caching of conextual links for views so that query parameters be taken into account?